# Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, range

Suppose I have a `std::vector` (let's call it `myVec`) of size `N`.  What's the simplest way to construct a new vector consisting of a copy of elements X through Y, where 0 <= X <= Y <= N-1?  For example, `myVec [100000]` through `myVec [100999]` in a vector of size `150000`.

If this cannot be done efficiently with a vector, is there another STL datatype that I should use instead?

Comment: you say you want to extract a subvector, but it seems to me that what you really want is a view / access to the subvector - difference being that a view would not copy - old school C++ would be to use start pointer and end pointer, given the fact that mem on a std::vector is contiguous,  then it should be possible for you to iterate using pointers and thereby avoid copy, however if you do not mind copy, then just initialize a new vector with the scope of your previous vector

Comment: There is .data()(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) since c++11. However, using pointers is discouraged within stl containers , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663770/c-safety-of-accessing-element-of-vector-via-pointers

Comment: @serup maybe not interested to OP but I would need to know how to " initialize a new vector with the scope of your previous vector".

Comment: Note) There's also [`assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) in std::vector, such as `v.assign(s.begin()+M, s.begin()+N);`

Answer (score 480, accepted):

```
vector<T>::const_iterator first = myVec.begin() + 100000;
vector<T>::const_iterator last = myVec.begin() + 101000;
vector<T> newVec(first, last);
```

It's an O(N) operation to construct the new vector, but there isn't really a better way.

Comment: +1, also it's O(Y-X), which is less than or equal to O(N) (and in his example much less)

Comment: @orip Well, then it's O(N) after all.

Comment: @GregRogers: It doesn't make sense to use the big-O notation where N is a specific number.  Big-O communicates the rate of growth with respect to how N changes.  Johann: It's best not to use one variable name in two ways.  We'd normally say either `O(Y-X)`, or we'd say `O(Z) where Z=Y-X`.

Comment: @GregRogers By using this way, we need to declare a new vector. Is there a way to change the original vector? something like myVec(first, last)? I know this is wrong, but I really need the solution as I want to use recursion in my codes, and need to repeatedly use the same vector (although changed). Thanks!

Comment: @ulyssis2 Create a new vector and swap?

Comment: Why not just `vector<T> newVec(myVec.begin() + 100000, myVec.begin() + 101000);`?

Comment: In addition, If `newVec` already exists and you want to replace it's contents use `newVec.asign(first, last)`. It has the same semantics as the constructor in the answer.

Comment: what happens if iterator last is outofbounds?

Comment: You can also use `auto` instead of `vector<T>::const_iterator`

Comment: Just for my own reference, the resulting vector is a shallow copy right? the sub-vector is not pointers to the original vectors underlying data structure right? I basically want to know that if I return back up a stackframe, that the internal pointers to the resulting sub-vector are still valid because they're separate from the original super-vector.

Comment: Is line 3 a copy? Is it possible to construct a reference subvector that way?

Comment: As a side note std::vector range constructor `constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last)`.

Comment: Great proposition. Could we use `auto cbegin` instead of `begin` ? ```auto first = myVec.cbegin() + 100000;
auto last = myVec.cbegin() + 101000;```

Comment: @AZTECCO that's the constructor this answer uses.

Comment: @pamplemousse_mk2 Yes.

Comment: @luizfls yes it is the constructor used, I thought pointing out that `last` element is not included was relevant , hence the [x,y) convention, in fact the answer used vector.begin + ..1000 to get ...999 elements

Comment: @DrDeo, i tried out of bounds `last` in a toy program: https://godbolt.org/z/87MsPqnWT

It doesn't do a bounds check. Compiler :clang 14.0.0, c++2a

Answer (score 110):

Just use the vector constructor.

```
std::vector<int>   data();
// Load Z elements into data so that Z > Y > X

std::vector<int>   sub(&data[100000],&data[101000]);
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize it was that simple to obtain an iterator from an arbitrary vector element.

Comment: Well, you actually get pointers to the elements, which in most cases are equivalent to iterators. However, I assume that they won't be checked like iterators when you have a checked-iterators implementation. Could be some magic I'm unaware of though that makes that work too...

Comment: Taking the address of those vector elements is an unportable hack that will break if the vector storage is not in fact contiguous.  Use begin() + 100000 etc.

Comment: My bad, apparently the standard guarantees that vector storage is contiguous.  Nevertheless it's bad practice to work with addresses like this as it is certainly not guaranteed to work for all containers supporting random access, while begin() + 100000 is.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Sorry have to disagree. The STL specification for std::vector was explicitly changed to support this type of procedure. Also a pointer is valid type of iterator. Look up iterator_traits<>

Comment: Yep, pointers aren't necessarily valid std::vector<T>::iterator's but they are valid iterators for an array in continuous storage, which is how it is used.

Comment: @Uri: This will always work. But like all code it is limited by system constraints. If you try and do something that is not physically possible you will get an exception.

Comment: How would you slice up to the last element using that ?
If you do sub(&data[100000],&data[data.size()]);
That would not always work and may throw an access violation ?

Comment: @taktak004 Nope. Remember that `operator[]` returns a reference. It is only at the point where you read or write the reference that it would become an access violation. Since we do neither but instead get the address we have not invoked UB,.

Comment: This won't work if you need to copy data till end of source vector.

Comment: @bialix: It will. I assume you are talking about taking the address of one past then end being the problem. This is covered by the standard and is allowed. It is UB to dereference this addresses but not to take its address. Note the definition of `X[Y]` is defined as `*(X + Y)` in the standard. And the operators `&*` placed together cancel each other out (assuming they have not been overridden (which they can't be for pointers)). => `&X[Y]` => `&*(X + Y)` => `(X + Y)`. Which is also why `10000[data]` is a valid expression for array access.

Comment: actually MSVC 2017 does raise an access violation for the case that @taktak004 considered (although only in Debug mode and with Debuglevel 2)

Answer (score 64):

This discussion is pretty old, but the simplest one isn't mentioned yet, with [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```cpp
 vector<int> subvector = {big_vector.begin() + 3, big_vector.end() - 2};
```

It requires c++11 or above.

Example usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> big_vector = {5,12,4,6,7,8,9,9,31,1,1,5,76,78,8};
    vector<int> subvector = {big_vector.begin() + 3, big_vector.end() - 2};

    cout << "Big vector: ";
    for_each(big_vector.begin(), big_vector.end(),[](int number){cout << number << ";";});
    cout << endl << "Subvector: ";
    for_each(subvector.begin(), subvector.end(),[](int number){cout << number << ";";});
    cout << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
Big vector: 5;12;4;6;7;8;9;9;31;1;1;5;76;78;8;
Subvector: 6;7;8;9;9;31;1;1;5;76;
```

Comment: it defines the subrange: Starts from the 3rd element, and goes until the 2nd from behind

Comment: Can you please clarify whether this way includes the last element?

Comment: It's inclusive, as the example shows: the last element is the one 2 positions before .end()

Comment: @DávidTóth It's exclusive. `.end()` returns the iterator to the "past the last" element.

Comment: inclusive for the last element, but exclusive of the "past the element" element..

Comment: Not important but to avoid confusion: In `vector<int> subvector = {iter1, iter2}`, `iter2` is exclusive. This does not change depending on your perspective. You said _"the last element is the one 2 positions before .end()"_, but it's not. The last element(`76`) is the one _3_ positions before `.end()`. Very tiny stuff but let's be careful :)

Answer (score 34):

These days, we use `span`s! So you would write:

```
#include <span>

...
auto start_pos = 100000;
auto length = 1000;
auto span_of_myvec = std::make_span(myvec);
auto my_subspan = span_of_myvec.subspan(start_pos, length);
```

to get a span of 1000 elements of the same type as `myvec`'s. Or a more terse form:

```
auto my_subspan = std::make_span(myvec).subspan(1000000, 1000);
```

(but I don't like this as much, since the meaning of each numeric argument is not entirely clear; and it gets worse if the length and start_pos are of the same order of magnitude.)

Anyway, remember that this is *not a copy, it's just a view* of the data in the vector, so be careful. If you want an actual copy, you could do:

```
std::vector<T> new_vec(my_subspan.cbegin(), my_subspan.cend());
```

Notes:

- If you use a version of C++ older than C++20, you can use `gsl::span` - from the Guidelines Support Library. For more information, see: http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guideline-the-guidelines-support-library and https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite for a concrete implementation
- For more information about spans, see: [What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one)
- `std::vector` has a gazillion constructors, it's super-easy to fall into one you didn't intend to use, so be careful.

Comment: would use `cbegin` and `cend` just for the principle ;) `std::cbegin` etc even.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Seeing how this code isn't templated on the choice of container, I don't see there's a particular benefit; a matter of taste I suppose.

Answer (score 32):

`std::vector<T>(input_iterator, input_iterator)`, in your case `foo = std::vector<T>(myVec.begin () + 100000, myVec.begin () + 150000);`, see for example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120120235758/http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx?manual=compleat&page=vector.html)

Comment: Since Andrew is trying to construct a new vector, I would recommend "std::vector foo(..." instead of copying with "foo = std::vector(..."

Comment: Yeah, of course, but whether you type std::vector<int> foo = std::vector(...) or std::vector<int> foo (...) should not matter.

Answer (score 12):

If both are not going to be modified (no adding/deleting items - modifying existing ones is fine as long as you pay heed to threading issues), you can simply pass around `data.begin() + 100000` and `data.begin() + 101000`, and pretend that they are the `begin()` and `end()` of a smaller vector.

Or, since vector storage is guaranteed to be contiguous, you can simply pass around a 1000 item array:

```
T *arrayOfT = &data[0] + 100000;
size_t arrayOfTLength = 1000;
```

Both these techniques take constant time, but require that the length of data doesn't increase, triggering a reallocation.

Comment: This is also good if you want the original vector and the subvector to be linked.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't mention what type `std::vector<...> myVec` is, but if it's a simple type or struct/class that doesn't include pointers, and you want the best efficiency, then you can do a direct memory copy (which I think will be faster than the other answers provided). Here is a general example for `std::vector<type> myVec` where `type` in this case is `int`:

```
typedef int type; //choose your custom type/struct/class
int iFirst = 100000; //first index to copy
int iLast = 101000; //last index + 1
int iLen = iLast - iFirst;
std::vector<type> newVec;
newVec.resize(iLen); //pre-allocate the space needed to write the data directly
memcpy(&newVec[0], &myVec[iFirst], iLen*sizeof(type)); //write directly to destination buffer from source buffer
```

Comment: I wonder if with -O3, @Anteru's "using constructor" `std::vector(myVec.begin () + 100000, myVec.begin () + 150000);` , wouldn't the longer-version of this produce into exactly the same assembly?

Comment: MSVC++ 2015, for example, compiles `std::vector<>(iter, iter)` to `memmove()`, if appropriate (if constructor is trivial, for a suitable definition of trivial).

Comment: Don't call `memcpy`. Do a `std::copy` or a constructor which accepts a range (two iterators), and the compiler and the std.library will conspire to call `memcpy` when appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use `insert`

```
vector<type> myVec { n_elements };

vector<type> newVec;

newVec.insert(newVec.begin(), myVec.begin() + X, myVec.begin() + Y);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [STL copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy.html) with O(M) performance when M is the size of the subvector.

Comment: Upvoted because it pointed me in the right direction but I can see why @LokiAstari suggests it's not the correct choice - since the STL::copy works with two std::vector<T> arrays of the same size and type. Here, the OP wants to copy a subsection into a new, smaller array as outlined here in the OP's post: "0 <= X <= Y <= N-1"

Comment: @Andrew, see example using std::copy and std::back_inserter

Comment: @LokiAstari why not?

Comment: @chrisg: The clue is in the name `copy`. To use std::copy you need to build the destination first (which means initializing all the members to the their default value). Then you can copy them over. So its two distinct operations. Why not simply use the vector constructor and initialize the members directly to their final values. See the nice answer that has +50 votes.

Comment: @LokiAstari  I was referring to an edit to this that did not survive peer review, which posed the example 
<br/>
vector<T> newvec;
std::copy(myvec.begin()+10000, myvec.begin() +10100, std::back_inserter(newvec));
<br/>
in this case, you don't need to build the destination first, but sure, direct initialization is more... direct.

Comment: @chrisg: Its also two lines. Additionally you need to stick a third line in to make sure it is efficient. `newvec.reserve(10100 - 10000);`. ITs definitely an option and technically it will work. But out of the two which are you going to recommend?

Comment: @LokiAstari ah, ok, I'm sold. The need for reserve on larger sets pushed me over the line. I also didn't like the "under the hood" feel of using naked pointers, dependency on an underlying detail (or "guarantee" that vector is contiguous), and unchecked array-like accessing, because they feel very C-like and un-C++-like, but then I decided its no worse than the iterator arithmetic used for std::copy approach

Comment: @chrisg: The most up-voted answer uses standard iterators and the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are two vectors.

```
 vector<int> vect1{1, 2, 3, 4};
 vector<int> vect2;
```

Method 1. Using copy function. copy(first_iterator_index, last_iterator_index, back_inserter()) :- This function takes 3 arguments, firstly, the first iterator of old vector. Secondly, the last iterator of old vector and third is back_inserter function to insert values from back.

```
    // Copying vector by copy function
    copy(vect1.begin(), vect1.end(), back_inserter(vect2));
```

Method 2. By using Assign Function. assign(first_iterator_o, last_iterator_o). This method assigns the same values to new vector as old one. This takes 2 arguments, first iterator to old vector and last iterator to old vector.

```
    //Copying vector by assign function
    vect2.assign(vect1.begin(), vect1.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to project a collection that is not linear time is to do so lazily, where the resulting "vector" is actually a subtype which delegates to the original collection.  For example, Scala's `List#subseq` method create a sub-sequence in constant time.  However, this only works if the collection is immutable and if the underlying language sports garbage collection.

Comment: in c++ way to do that would be to have vector of shared_ptr to X instead of vector of X and then copy SPs, but unfortunately I dont think that is faster because atomic operation involved with cpying SP. Or the original vector could be a const shared_ptr of vector instead and you just take reference to subrange in it. ofc you dont need to make it a shared_ptr of vector but then you have lifetime problems... all this is off top of my head, could be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [array_view/span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832090/whats-the-difference-between-span-and-array-view-in-the-gsl-library) in the GSL library is a good option.

Here is also a single file implementation: [array_view](https://github.com/rhysd/array_view).

Comment: Kindly add answer here along with link. As external link might change in future

Answer (score 0):

**Copy elements from one vector to another easily**

In this example, I am using a vector of pairs to make it easy to understand

`

```
vector<pair<int, int> > v(n);

//we want half of elements in vector a and another half in vector b
vector<pair<lli, lli> > a(v.begin(),v.begin()+n/2);
vector<pair<lli, lli> > b(v.begin()+n/2, v.end());


//if v = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
//then a = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
//and b = [(3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

//if v = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
//then a = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
//and b = [(4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

'

As you can see you can easily copy elements from one vector to another, if you want to copy elements from index 10 to 16 for example then we would use

```
vector<pair<int, int> > a(v.begin()+10, v.begin+16);
```

and if you want elements from index 10 to some index from end, then in that case

```
vector<pair<int, int> > a(v.begin()+10, v.end()-5);
```

hope this helps, just remember in the last case `v.end()-5 > v.begin()+10`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:
Useful for instance when moving between a `thrust::device_vector` and a `thrust::host_vector`, where you cannot use the constructor.

```
std::vector<T> newVector;
newVector.reserve(1000);
std::copy_n(&vec[100000], 1000, std::back_inserter(newVector));
```

Should also be complexity O(N)

You could combine this with top anwer code

```
vector<T>::const_iterator first = myVec.begin() + 100000;
vector<T>::const_iterator last = myVec.begin() + 101000;
std::copy(first, last, std::back_inserter(newVector));
```

Answer (score 0):

`vector::assign` may be another solution

```
// note: size1 < src.size() && size2 < src.size()
std::vector<int> sub1(size1), sub2(size2);
sub1.assign(src.begin(), src.begin() + size1);
sub2.assign(src.begin(), src.begin() + size2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Posting this late just for others..I bet the first coder is done by now.
For simple datatypes no copy is needed, just revert to good old C code methods.

```
std::vector <int>   myVec;
int *p;
// Add some data here and set start, then
p=myVec.data()+start;
```

Then pass the pointer p and a len to anything needing a subvector.

notelen must be!! `len < myVec.size()-start`

Comment: This doesn't perform a copy.