# Extract element from 2 vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, containers

I have 2 vector of with one has vec1{e1,e2,e3,e4}  and the other one with vec2 {e2,e4,e5,e7}

How to effectively get three vector from above vectors such that 1.has elements that is available only in vec1 similarly 2 has only vec2 elements  and 3.with common elements

Comment: What's the type of elements? Are they comparable? Are there only 4 elements?

Comment: yes they are comparable and not just 4 element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::set_intersection` should do the trick, if both vectors are sorted:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfd331yx.aspx

```
std::set_intersection(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(vec3));
```

A custom predicate can be used for the comparison too:

```
std::set_intersection(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(vec3), my_equal_functor());
```

If they are not sorted, you may of course sort them first, or alternatively, you can iterate through vec1, and for each element, use std::find to see if it exists in vec2.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is that `vec3` be the *intersection* of the other two. Jalf demonstrates how to populate `vec3` using the `std::set_intersection` function from [the `<algorithm>` header](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=algorith.html). But remember that for the set functions to work, **the vectors must be sorted**.

Then you want `vec1` and `vec2` to be the *difference* between themselves and `vec3`. In set notation:

```
vec1 := vec1 \ vec3;
vec2 := vec2 \ vec3;
```

You can use the `std::set_difference` function for that, but you can't use it to modify the vectors in-place. You'd have to compute another vector to hold the difference:

```
std::vector<foo> temp;
std::set_difference(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),
                    vec3.begin(), vec3.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(temp));
vec1 = temp;
temp.clear();
std::set_difference(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),
                    vec3.begin(), vec3.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(temp));
vec2 = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element count is low, you can use the naive approach which is easy to implement and has O(n<sup>2</sup>) running time.

If you have a large number of elements, you can build a hash table from one of them and look up other vector's elements in it. Alternatively, you could sort one of them and binary search through it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is vector intersection. This depends on the size of the input vectors.

If the sizes of both vectors are close to each other a merge (like in merge-sort) is best. If one vector is much smaller than the other do the following: For each element of the smaller vector search for that element in the larger vector using binary search.

This is a common problem in information retrieval, where you have to intersect inverted indices. There are some research papers on this.