# Creating a new C++ subvector?

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a vector with values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. I want to create a new vector that refers to, for example, [5,6,7,8]. I imagine this is just a matter of creating a vector with pointers or do I have to push_back all the intermediary values I need?

Comment: The given answers so far are all good options.  While you *could* create a vector of pointers to your subrange, you probably don't want to.  If the original vector ever grows to the point where it has to re-allocate its internal storage, your pointers would all become invalid.  Especially when dealing with such small ranges, working with a copy is preferable.

Comment: Define "refers to". What should happen if the original vector changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

One of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)'s constructor accepts a range:

```
std::vector<int> v;

// Populate v.
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) v.push_back(i);   

// Construct v1 from subrange in v.
std::vector<int> v1(v.begin() + 4, v.end() - 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use `push_back` if you don't want to, you can use `std::copy`:

```
std::vector<int> subvector;
copy ( v1.begin() + 4, v1.begin() + 8, std::back_inserter(subvector) );
```

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize subvector to the correct size before copying into it?

Comment: @obmarg, or you could use some form of `insert_iterator`.

Comment: @obmarg yes or use a back insertion iterator - `std::back_inserter` will make one for you

Comment: @Kristo (and @awoodland) Yes.  Though from my experience they tend to be slow, do they not just use push_back behind the scenes?

Comment: Inserting one element at a time (as `insert_iterator`s do) will usually be slower than inserting a range all at once.  But for vectors of such small size as this example, I doubt it matters.

Comment: you can always use `reserve()` with an insertion iterator to avoid reallocation too.

Comment: Since it's been 30 minutes and @Luchian hasn't noticed our comments yet, I went ahead and edited the code.

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly easy to do with `std::valarray` instead of a vector:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  const std::valarray<int> arr={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

  const std::valarray<int>& slice = arr[std::slice(5, // start pos
                                                   4, // size
                                                   1  // stride
                                                  )];

}
```

Which takes a "slice" of the valarray, more generically than a vector.

For a vector you can do it with the constructor that takes two iterators though:

```
const std::vector<int> arr={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
std::vector<int> slice(arr.begin()+5, arr.begin()+9);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printvec(vector<int>& v){
        for(int i = 0;i < v.size();i++){
                cout << v[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
}

int main(){
        vector<int> v;

        for(int i = 1;i <= 10;i++) v.push_back(i);
        printvec(v);

        vector<int> v2(v.begin()+4, v.end()-2);
        printvec(v2);
        return 0;
}
```

~