# Error when splicing a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, splice

I'm trying to splice a vector in C++ using the following code:

`sequence(sequence.begin() + i, sequence.end());`

where `sequence` is a vector containing integers and `i` is an integer, but when I run my code it gives the following error:

`error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int>) (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*,
std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
         sequence(sequence.begin() + i, sequence.end());
                                                      ^`

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. I used the following stack overflow questions to help write this code:

[Creating a new C++ subvector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705441/creating-a-new-c-subvector)

[Slicing a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110523/slicing-a-vector)

Comment: May I suggest you read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, because `sequence` doesn't have an overloaded call operator. You can only use that syntax when initializing objects when you are defining them:

```
int i(1); // ok
i(2); // nope!
```

You are trying to do the second line above, which fails because it's not a valid form of initialization in this context. If you want to splice a vector, you can use [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase);

```
sequence.erase(sequence.begin() + i, sequence.end()); // erases [start, end)
```