# Read data in a specific position in a std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, vector, position

I have an `std::vector<unsigned char>` with binary data in.

I just would like to simply read this vector, in a specific position with a specific size.

I would a function like this :

```
myvector.read(PositionBegin, Size)
myvector.read(1200,3)
```

This function could be read data from `1200`, to `1203`.

Is there a function like this in C++ ?

Comment: I don't think vector is really the structure you want to be using for this task. Take a look through this [STL reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) and see is there's something that might better suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want another std::vector with the range out...

This link provides a good answer: [Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector)

your function could look like:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> readFromVector(const std::vector<unsigned char> &myVec,
        unsigned start, unsigned len)
{
    // Replaced T with unsigned char (you could/should templatize...)
    std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator first = myVec.begin() + start;
    std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator last = first + len;
    std::vector<unsigned char> newVec(first, last);
    return newVec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use appropriate tags for your questions.

a simple iterator thrue your vector:

```
for (i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++)
cout << " " << myvector.at(i);
cout << endl;
```

so if you wanted to use a range, you just need to set your for loop constraints

```
for (i=PositionBegin; i<PositionBegin+Size; i++)
cout << " " << myvector.at(i);
cout << endl;
```

If you want this function to output this to another vector,
instead of using cout, you have to push it in a new vector.

```
mynewvector.push_back(myvector.at(i));
```

Don't forget that when you are making this function you have to make it with a type:

```
vector<type> function()
```

and at the end:

```
return mynewvector;
```

read up on vectors at :[cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)