# HOG Descriptor Vector layout and how to save them to text file

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to open CV so currently struggling with it. I have extracted HOG features using following definition:

```
HOGDescriptor hog(Size(16,16), Size(16,16), Size(16,16), Size(8,8), 9);
```

It returns 36 dimensional feature vector / pixel.  Now I want to separate all these 36 values in a row and save it in text file. I don't know how to do it.  Please do guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you compute the features, i.e. `descriptors` by [`cv::HOGDescriptor::compute`](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a5ce15ef09b0eb7d0ecfd7f2eb353df83), it's a `vector<float>`, so just access it like normal `vector<float>`s.

And if you want to split them into `36`-by-`36` style, you can do like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<descriptors.size()/36; i++)
{
    // ... handle 36 values here
    for (int j=0; j<36; j++)
    {
        if (36*i+j < descriptors.size()) // make sure not out-of-bound
        {
            float temp = descriptors[36*i+j];
            ...
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I need to get first 36 values then next 36 and so on ...is their anything in open CV like descriptors(1:36) (as its in Matlab)?

Comment: @user3319734 I found one way to do this, check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/421615/2589776). Or simply use a `for`-loop.

Comment: could you please write a for loop for that?

Comment: so "temp" will have 36 values?

Comment: @user3319734 `temp` is a `float`... You need to learn basic stuff of `C++`. Start from this [book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks ... can I change temp to array of 36 dimensions, and then in the inner most loop temp array fills values ?