# How to get subarray of C-Array

Tags: c++, filter, arrays

I am trying to find out what is the easiest way to get a subset of C-Array if there are start and end points give.

Example: I have a class Trip:

```
class Trip
{
  private:
  char* final_destination;
  char* description;
  public:
  //all constructors, operators and stuff
};
```

And, lets say I have an array of Trips:

```
Trip* trips = new Trip[10];
```

I am trying to write a function that takes the Trip array, starting point(given destination), end point(given destination) and return a subset of type Trip*.

E.g.

```
Trip* GetSubTrip(Trip* trips, char* start_point, char* end_point)
{
  //Logics that returns Trip*
}
```

In other words, If I had:

```
[{"London", "Big Ben"}, {"New York", "Manhattan"}, {"Paris", "Eifell Tower"}, {"Moscow", "Lots of fun"}]
```

That would be the **Trip* trips** and "New York" as a start and "Moscow" as an end passed to the **GetSubTrip** I am trying to make it return Trip*.

And the return has to be:

```
[{"Paris", "Eifell Tower"}, {"Moscow", "Lots of fun"}]
```

What I do is:

1. In an integer counter I get the length between start and end
2. Create a new pointer Trip* and assign it with length of the counter from 1
3. Iterate over the 'trips' parameter and keeping a track if I am between start and end and if yes-> add the object to the result else procceed further.

But this is a lot of code. I am sure that there is much easier way.

**EDIT:**

**It has to be done WITHOUT the use of VECTOR!**

Comment: I see no sense in returning anything besides a sequence of two or more *indexes* into the original array of `Trip[]` using possibly a `std::vector<unsigned int>`. The data is already there; you just need something with which to reference it.

Comment: I edited my question. It has to be done without the use of vector object.

Comment: Ok. Because... ? (and regardless, dyna-alloc your own sequence then and manage the size. either way, making copies of `Trip`s isn't needed. If the goal is a single pair of indexes (where to start, where to stop) then return a `std::pair<int,int>` or some such. Use your own struct if desired.

Comment: Assuming you need a deep copy I'd suggest to use two integer numbers `startIdx` and `endIdx` and then use a simple for loop `for (int i = startIdx; i < endIdx; i++) { subtrips[i-startIdx]=trips[i] }`  That probably eliminates the awkward if clause that checks if being inbetween start and end.

Comment: `-1` for "without the use of VECTOR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Trip> route;
bool go = false; 
for( int i=0; i<tripsSize /* trips[i] != TRIP_GUARD */; ++i ) 
{ 
    if( go ) 
    { 
         route.push_back( trips[i] );
         if( trips[i] == end ) 
             break; 
    } 
    else if( trips[i] == start ) 
        go = true; 
}
```

Why use `std::vector`? You don't have to keep the size of resulting array. You may modify it freely and conveniently. You don't have to worry about memory allocation for `Trip` objects.

In case you don't want to use `std::vector` you would need some sort of guard for both of your arrays (input and output one ) or to pass length of the array.

Without `std::vector`:

```
Trip * route;
int tripsNum;
int startNum, endNum;
for( int i=0; i<tripsSize /* trips[i] != TRIP_GUARD */; ++i ) 
{ 
    if( trips[i] == start ) 
        startNum = i;
    else if( trips[i] == end )
    { 
        endNum = i; 
        break;
    }
}
tripsNum = endNum - startNum;
route = new Trip[ tripsNum ];
for( int i=startNum + 1, j=0; i<=endNum; ++i, ++j )
    route[ j ] = trips [ i ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++ you can consider using std::vector class instead of raw C arrays.

For raw C arrays you would need to keep the size (number of elements) of the array somewhere.
If you prefer arrays the solution depends on whether you are going to modify the original array/sub-arrays.
If you don't modify the Trips array, you can get the pointer to the sub-array with pointer arithmetic:

```
return trips + 2;//The returned pointer points to {"Paris", "Eifell Tower"}
```

You would also need to store the size of the sub-array.

If you do need to modify the original array (and/or sub-array), then you would have to create a copy (I would strongly suggest using vectors in that case). You might find this useful:
[Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector)