# How to (re)move from a container if predicate is satisfied?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, move-semantics, stl-algorithm

How can I move the element into `aux_list` using STL algorithm module?

```
std::remove_copy_if( list.begin( ), list.end( ), std::back_inserter( aux_list ),
                     []( const value_type& item_ptr )
                     {
                         return !item_ptr->is_valid( );
                     } );
```

Comment: So instead of copying from `list` to `aux_list` you want to move the elements?

Comment: Note that, contrary to what the name suggests, `remove_copy_if` does not actually remove anything.

Comment: I actually asked a similar question before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320577/remove-elements-from-range-and-copy-removed-elements-to-new-range

Comment: Is your container an actual `std::list`? In that case you should use the `splice` member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [move iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator):

```
std::remove_copy_if(
    std::make_move_iterator(list.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(list.end()),
    std::back_inserter(aux_list),
    [](const value_type& item_ptr) { return !item_ptr->valid(); });
```

Note that the elements still all exist in `list` - they weren't actually removed (this is a weirdly named algorithm - think of it as `copy_unless()`). So now you will have a bunch of elements in an unspecified state.