# C++ - Safety of accessing element of vector via pointers

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, type-safety

In a C++ project of mine, I am using a `vector` to hold a bunch of `struct`s which hold a number of elements for a simple game (ie: tic-tac-toe, coordinates, `x` vs `o`, etc). ie:

```
struct gameMove
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int player;
  int order;
};
```

Every time during a single game, whenever a player makes a move (ie: places an `x` or `o`), the information is stored in the `vector` via `push_back()`, to create an "undo" feature, which currently works as expected.

In some parts of my undo/redo logic, I am using functions which traverse the `vector`, find the appropriate element, and return a pointer directly to that element.

Is it safe, so long as I'm correctly managing the `vector`, access to it, NULL-ing out all the pointers that point to elements of the `vector`, or are there inherent risks? My concern is that if extend the game, which I plan to do (ie: use the same code for a chess game I'm working on), and that the `vector` gets too large and needs to be automagically re-allocated, the pointers will become invalid (ie: entire list is moved to a new contiguous block that can fit all the elements), or is there some type of smart-pointer interface to `vector` to accomplish the same thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct to be concerned: If the vector needs to grow, the addresses in the `vector` will change (or if the vector shrinks, but most implementations of `vector` doesn't shrink without some effort from the programmer).

The immediately simple solution would be to return the index into the vector, instead of a pointer. That, as long as it's in range, will always be a valid way to find a particular element. [And instead of `NULL` you could use for example `-1` or `0xDEAD`]

Comment: If I know for certain an upper limit on the number of elements in the `vector`, is it possible to set the max `vector` size in advance, guaranteeing it never re-sizes?

Comment: @Dogbert You can use `reserve` to allocate the memory you need in advance, but why go through the trouble if you can use an index rather than a pointer, as mentioned by this answer?

Comment: As mentioned, `reserve` will guarantee that the `vector` doesn't get re-allocated [until the reserved limit is reached], but I fail to see the benefit... Unless you plan on more than 4 billion records, pointers are larger than integers [in 64-bit architectures, which is the norm these days, even on mobile phones!]

Comment: Unless things changed in C++11, `vector` is guaranteed not to reallocate when elements are deleted or when `reserve()` is called with a value smaller than the current capacity.  From 23.2.4.2/2 of the C++03 standard: "Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve()."

Comment: @JorenHeit The reason I'd like to avoid the index approach is because it would require an internal API re-write which I'd like to avoid if safely possible, and possibly the use of a global variable.

Comment: One thing I'd also forgotten to ask: If I delete some elements from the `vector` via `erase_at()`, will adding new elements via `push_back()` re-use the freed-up space in the contiguous list, or will it just append to the list instead. I know I'll only use up to say 50 elements, but during testing, might repeatedly add/remove items several times. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if I store the index, and later have to delete some arbitrary element via `erase_at()`, then the index values are no longer valid.

Comment: That applies to pointers too - if you have a pointer to element 6, and you "erase" element 4, then the pointer should now point to the new element 5, but it is actually pointing at the new element 6, so the same exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `std::stack` or the `std::list`? The stack especially could be appealing for simplifying the "undo" functionality you're looking for (since the last move will always be the top of the stack). But with the linked structure, you wouldn't need to worry so much about the indexing issue, though if you're tight on memory they may not be the best option...