# Extract a subvector from a vector with iterator

Tags: c++, vector

i'm trying to extract a subvector of int from another subvector of int using iterator with this code :

`std::vector<int> Original;
std::vector<int> NewVec;

NewVec(Original.begin(), Original.begin()+5);`

and this doesn't work, only if i declare NewVec in the same line of extraction like that :

`std::vector<int> NewVec(Original.begin(), Original.begin()+5);`

So, is it possible to use NewVec such that its declaration is before its construction ?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to assign a subrange to an existing `std::vector` you can use the `assign()` member:

```
NewVec.assign(Original.begin(), Original.begin() + 5);
```

Of course, this assumes that `Original` has at least 5 elements.

Comment: for learners) `assign` resets the vector. i.e. the original elements of the `NewVec` in the above code are all removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::copy`:

```
NewVec.reserve(5);
std::copy(std::begin(Original), std::begin(Original)+5,
          std::back_inserter(NewVec));
```

Or `std::vector::assign`:

```
NewVec.assign(std::begin(Original), std::begin(Original)+5);
```

Comment: what if you don't use `reserve` or `resize`?

Comment: @Jepessen `reserve` is just to avoid unnecessary allocations when inserting into the vector. In this case I doubt it'd make any difference as the vector is very small, but I tend to `reserve` whenever I `std::copy` so that I don't forget when it matters.

Comment: @Jepessen: the `reserve()` is a potential optimization, avoiding relocation of the `std::vector`'s element. The `resize()` in the above use is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok got it. So it's a performance issue... thanks for explanation.