# What's the difference between span and array_view in the gsl library?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library, array-view

In several recent conference presentation I've heard Bjarne Stroustrup and others mention new coding guidelines for C++ and some types supporting them.

Specifically, I remember [the example of `span<T>` instead of `(T* p, int n)` as a parameter to a function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8NLSL7dALo) (at time about 32:00 into the talk); but I also remember the suggestion to use `array_view<T>`. Are they two alternatives but the same concept? Or am I confusing things and they're actually not so related?

I can't seem to find any authoritative definition of what they're both supposed to be about.

Comment: @DavidHaim: See edit, as well as [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/span.h) for example.

Comment: There are array view implementations and proposals in the wild.  Have you looked at them?

Comment: I believe that `array_view` was renamed to `span`.

Comment: @Galik: Can you provide evidence? If you can, write it as an answer and I'll accept...

Comment: @Yakk: Well, yes, a bit, but I seem to see things which are not necessarily related, like part of Microsoft C++ AMP etc. I figured there might be more than one thing named `array_view` floating around.

Comment: @einpoklum I added a link to my answer where the renaming was announced

Answer (score 205, accepted):

We talked with people in the [library working group](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/) in the [standards committee](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee). They wanted the `array_view` they are trying to get into the standard to be read only. For the core guidelines, we needed an abstraction that was read and write. To avoid a clash between the (potential) standards and the guidelines support library (GSL), we renamed our (read and write) `array_view` to `span`: https://github.com/microsoft/gsl .

Comment: And `const array_view<T>` plus `array view<const T>` wasn't satisfactory?

Comment: Thanks for being committed to the zero cost abstractions mantra - I really do think `span` would save a lot of programmers from making silly errors. I think communicating these new changes could be done in a clearer way though. I'm just wondering - wouldn't this be something that could be solved as clearly with a regular random access iterator? Was the type added just for clarity?

Comment: This was a talk on resources and dangling pointers. span and the GSL was a side issue. Have a look at Neil MacIntosh's CppCon 2015 talk: “Evolving array_view and string_view for safe C++ code" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Z3c4Sv52U and/or have a look at the GSL source: https://github.com/microsoft/gsl . We are also working on a formal (standard style) specification.

Comment: There was a worry that "view" implied just looking at the contents, not modifying them, so some folks wanted a different suffix for the read/write version. I don't think anyone cares much about a read-only array_view type existing. It's string_view that people care be read-only by default.

Comment: As a graphics coder where 'view' merely means one's current view into read/write data (e.g. glViewPort, D3D's SetViewport), making "view" read-only is surprising, but outside graphics, I suppose I could see 'view' feeling more like a read-only window than a read/write window.

Comment: Thankfully the GSL is just GSL and not C++ nor standard whatsoever.

Comment: So it is for people that can't handle typing "const" or making a typedef. That's why we need 2 types for an array_view.

Answer (score 52):

In the [CppCoreGuidlines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) The original `array_view` was renamed to `span`.

See: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/pull/377

It is described thus:

> span is a bounds-checked, safe alternative to using pointers to access arrays

Comment: I +1'd you, but Bjarne Stroustrup (really?)'s answer is more detailed.

Comment: @einpoklum No, I get it. I'd have probably chosen Bjarne Stroustrup over me too. Not (sniff) taking (sniff) it (sniff) personal (wahhhhhh)...

Comment: That comment made me feel something inside, so +1 from me, too ;-)

Answer (score 14):

The document [P0122R](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0122r1.pdf) (2016-02-12) from the *Library Evolution Working Group* (LEWG)
**officially renames the type `array_view` to `span`**:

> ### Changelog
>
> #### Changes from R0
>
> - Changed the name of the type being proposed from `array_view` to `span` following feedback from LEWG at the Kona meeting.
> - [...]

We can also read:

> ### Impact on the Standard
>
> This proposal is a pure library extension.
>   It does not require any changes to standard classes, functions, or headers.
>   It would be enhanced if could depends on the `byte` type 
>   and changes to type aliasing behavior proposed in [P0257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0257r0.html).
>
> However – if adopted – it may be useful to overload some standard library functions for this new type (an example would be `copy()`).
>
> `span` has been implemented in standard C++ (C++11) and is being successfully
>   used within a commercial static analysis tool for C++ code as well as commercial office productivity software. 
>   An open source, reference implementation is available at https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL.

In a next chapter, this documents presents the *read-only* and *read-write* (*mutable*) accesses:

> ### Element types and conversions
>
> `span` must be configured with its element type
>   via the template parameter `ValueType`,
>   which is required to be a complete object type 
>   that is not an abstract class type.
>   `span` supports either read-only or mutable access to the sequence it encapsulates.
>   To access read-only data, the user can declare a `span<const T>`, 
>   and access to mutable data would use a `span<T>`.
>
> [...]

---

See also the [*Guidelines Support Library Review: `span<T>`*](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2016/03/07/guidelines-support-library-review-spant/) from Marius Bancila (march 2016) defining `span` as:

> The [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) is a Microsoft implementation 
>   of some of the types and functions described in the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) 
>   maintained by the [Standard C++ Foundation](https://isocpp.org/). 
>   Among the types provided by the GSL is `span<T>` formerly known as `array_view<T>`.
>
> `span<T>` is a non-owning range of contiguous memory recommended to be used instead of 
>   pointers (and size counter) or standard containers (such as `std::vector` or `std::array`).