# Rules for returning fake object reference in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, semantics, dereference

I would like to iterate through a pre-allocated float array with a custom container that does not owns the data, but acts on a segment of it. Example, naming the container class `LinhaSobre`:

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> data(new float[720]);
...
//creates container to iterate 26 floats starting from from data[12]
    LinhaSobre cont(data.get()+12, 26); 
//sets those elements to 1.5
    for(size_t i = 0; i < cont.size(); i++)
        cont[i] = 1.5f;
```

Here's a possible implementation of the `operator[]` :

```
//...
//LinhaSobre has a member mem0 which is initialized
//as a pointer to where the interval starts
float & LinhaSobre::operator[] (size_t i)
{
    return *(mem0+i);
}
```

Notice that I'm returning a reference from `LinhaSobre::operator[]` to data that it does not owns. It should not interfere with the data's lifetime (constructors, destructors).

Now I want to expose the stored `data` by another pattern, `std::array<float,4>`, and not pure `float`. Example, naming the new class `LinhaSobre4f`:

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> data(new float[720]);
...
//creates container to iterate 4 array<float, 4> starting from from data[12]
    LinhaSobre4f l(data.get()+(3*4), 4);
//sets those elements to {1.5f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 4.5f};
    for(size_t i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
        l[i] = { {1.5f, 2.5f, 3.5f, 4.5f} };
```

Notice that I treat the items as an array.
This would lead to some changes in the container class, my main concern is with the `operator[]`, here's the full class code:

```
struct LinhaSobre4f
{
    LinhaSobre4f(float * pos_begin, size_t size_):
        pos0(pos_begin),
        size_(size_){}
    std::array<float, 4> & operator[](size_t i)const
    {
        std::array<float,4> * r = 
            reinterpret_cast<std::array<float,4>*> (pos0+(4*i));
        return *r;
    }
    size_t size()const
    {
        return size_;
    }
private:
    float * pos0;
    size_t size_;
};
```

The `operator[]` returns a reference to a block of memory treated as an `std::array<float,4>` that never really existed as such, but given the `std::array` memory layout guaranties, it works. I'm dubious about this, is it OK? (aside from memory alignment, which I'll guarantee). Am I allowed to expose an object like this, semantically? What is the correct term for this? (I've used *fake object* in the title).

[Here's a live demo of the example](http://cpp.sh/9my2z). [Here's another (the other link sometimes fails)](http://ideone.com/mB6s81)

Comment: One thing which definitely stands out to me (and the compiler will warn you about this) is that in `operator[]` of `LinhaSobre4f` you are returning a reference to a temporary variable - you should change the signature of this method to return by value instead of reference.

Comment: (Am I?) The local (temporary) variable is a pointer, and I'm returning the dereference of it, not a reference to it.

Comment: I *think* you're safe, though I have nothing to back it up.

Comment: *"Example, naming the container class `LinhaSobre`"* => Wouldn't `Container` be less distracting?

Comment: @Kahler actually I might be wrong there, it should be safe with pointers.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard (I'm reading C++11) defines a `std::array` as follows:

> The conditions for an aggregate (8.5.1) shall be met.

You are not guaranteed that a `std::array` is a POD. The C++ standard guarantees only that it's a class aggregate.

Based on that, I believe that your usage of `reinterpret_cast` to convert a POD array of `float`s to a `std::array` is undefined behavior.

Chances are that it'll work, with your compiler, but you are not guaranteed that this will be portable, or legal.

Comment: Searching about it, I've encountered the [std::is_pod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod), can I assume it's safe if [it returns true to std::array<float, 4>](http://ideone.com/ez6sX4)?

Comment: It is safe if it returns true with your current compiler. However, keep in mind that if it returns true with your current compiler, there are no guarantees that it will return true with any other compiler, or any future or previous version of your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You might create a plain old reference_type:

```
struct LinhaSobre4f {
    struct Ref {
        Ref(float *m): m(m){};
        Ref &operator=(std::initializer_list<float> const &l) {
            std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), m);
            return *this;
        }
    private:
        float *m;
    };
    Ref operator[](size_t i) { return m + 4 * i; }
private:
    float *m;
};
```

Comment: I understand the delegation, but the `operator[]` now returns a value, not a reference... My desire was to be able to operate directly in the  data, apart that `Ref` now has to implement every desired operation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on Sam Varshavchik's answer, you may be interested in the `span` type ([formerly known as `array_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34832090/3235496)).

The `span` type is an abstraction that provides a view over a contiguous sequence of objects, the storage of which is owned by some other object (more details in [P0122R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0122r1.pdf), [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) and [Guidelines Support Library Review: `span<T>`](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2016/03/07/guidelines-support-library-review-spant/)).

Conceptually, a `span` is simply a pointer to some storage and a count of the elements accessible via that pointer. It's so small that it can be passed by value.

An open source (header only), reference implementation is available at https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL (the implementation generally assumes a platform that implements C++14 support. There are specific workarounds to support MSVC 2013 and 2015).