# Time complexity of: v(arr.begin(),arr.end)

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

Can anybody tell me what is the time complexity of this:

`vector<int>arr;
vector<int>v(arr.begin(),arr.end());`

Is is it O(N) or O(1) ?

Comment: Do you want the complexity of this code in isolation, or is there some process filling `arr` with data?

Comment: O(N), discussed for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector). However, In the example you show, the time will be 0, as `arr` is empty.

Comment: Ignoring the question of how many items are in `arr`... how could it be O(1)?

Comment: Think about it. You're copying every element of `arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is O(N). v's constructor has to construct the elements from arr having setup the memory for it. N is arr.size()