# How to ensure one time memory allocation while creating a std::vector from another container?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, allocation

When I need to make an `std::vector` from some elements of another container, e.g. another vector, the safest way to ensure that the new vector will be allocated in memory only once is:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
const size_t amount = 3;
std::vector<int> v2;
v2.reserve(amount);
v2.insert(v2.begin(), v1.begin(), v1.begin() + amount);
```

Meanwhile this code is much longer than very simple constructions from [Best way to extract a subvector from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector) like

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
const size_t amount = 3;
std::vector<int> v2(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + amount);
```

or

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
const size_t amount = 3;
std::vector<int> v2 = {v1.begin(), v1.begin() + amount};
```

The questions is: do the latter cases ensure that memory for `v2` will be allocated only once or the specific implementation could easy use something like cycle of `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` and lead to many container memory reallocation during its creation as a copy?

Is is guaranteed by the standard or at least can I rely on existing implementations that they won't reallocate memory many times?

I am concerned because I work with huge containers and want to make sure this more readable code won't have performance impact.

Comment: _"do the latter cases ensure that memory for v2 will be allocated only once"_ - I'm not sure what the standard says, but it would seem strange if they didn't `reserve` internally if given random access iterators. It'd be harder if you populated it from a `std::list` though. Then I would do it like you do it, manually reserving first, then `insert` or `assign`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this passage in the C++23 standard:

> 24.3.11.2 Constructors [vector.cons]
>
> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
> constexpr vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
> const Allocator& = Allocator());
> ```
>
> 9. Effects: Constructs a `vector` equal to the range `[first, last)`, using the specified allocator.
> 10. Complexity: Makes only N calls to the copy constructor of T (where N is the distance between first and last) and **no reallocations if iterators first and last are of forward, bidirectional, or random access categories**. It makes order N calls to the copy constructor of T and order log N reallocations if they are just input iterators.

That means a conforming implementation will do it as least as efficiently as your manual call to `reserve` + `insert`.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I copy from std::list which has a *LegacyBidirectionalIterator*, is this iterator considered "bidirectional" category or being *LegacyIterator* it doesn't fit here and reallocations will occur?

Comment: @DamirTenishev You're welcome! I assumed that reallocations could occur for `std::list::iterator`s since `last - first` can't be performed in constant time, but the standard says otherwise. I guess that means that it'll have to run through the whole range to count elements first if given non-random access forward/bidirectional iterators.

Comment: I see. The question is more about terms in the standard; namely, could the *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* considered a "bidirectional" category in the context above or somewhere is standard it is explicitly said that these (legacy and new) hierarchies are different with different behaviors and requirements and it can't be considered as such.
As for counting through the list, I guess that in the most sensible cases such counting (if even necessary and the amount is not cached) will be much cheaper than reallocations (for real-time systems and memory constrained controllers).

Comment: @DamirTenishev Yes, the LegacyBidirectionalIterator counts as bidirectional in this context. The standard doesn't mention what techniques to use, only the complexity requirements. I agree that counting first is probably reasonable for these iterators. I just wasn't expecting that requierment on anything but RandomAccessIterators :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector#Complexity, the 5th listed constructor (for two iterators), for non-input iterators no reallocation happens. The constructor has to do the equivalent of `reserve(distance(first, last))` to be standards-compliant.

So your `std::vector<int> v2(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + amount);` will have exactly one allocation.

Comment: Thank you. So, does this `std::vector<int> v2 = {v1.begin(), v1.begin() + amount};` cover too? (I accepted the answer from Ted just because of the reference to standard, although they are absolutely equal and useful (marked both); sorry for this choice).